# Load more listview fail update data

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, endlessscroll

I have listview show Name, School and Link get from URL. Each one URL have 30 items so-called i use load more item of listview. But when re-call Asynctask new data not append. When run app give me NullpointerException.
If you know... Please help me.
Thanks all.

Sorry.I speak English not good!

My code here :

class InfoTeacherFragment

```
public class InfoTeacherFragment extends Fragment {

    private String URL = "http://scv.udn.vn/dhdn/trdhsp/page/";
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<ItemTeacher> data;
    ItemTeacher itemTeacher = new ItemTeacher();
    ListView lvItem;
    DisplayImageOptions options;
    ImageLoader imageloader;
    View mFooterView;
    InfoTeacher adapter;
    ProgressBar loading;
    int CurrentPage = 1;
    int visibleThreshold = 3;
    int startPage = 1;
    boolean loadingMore = false;

    public InfoTeacherFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_mission)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error).cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true).considerExifParams(true)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.teacherinfo_layout,
                container, false);
        mContext = container.getContext();
        lvItem = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvTeacher);
        data = new ArrayList<ItemTeacher>();
        adapter = new InfoTeacher(mContext, data);
        lvItem.setAdapter(adapter);
        lvItem.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
                CurrentPage++;
                customLoadMoreDataFromApi(CurrentPage);

            }
        });
        imageloader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageloader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(mContext));
        if (Utils.isOnline(mContext) == true
                && Utils.KEY_CHECK_SUCCESS.equals("SUCCESS")) {
            loadDataFromServer(URL + startPage);
        } else if (Utils.isOnline(mContext) == true
                && Utils.KEY_CHECK_SUCCESS.equals("FAIL")) {
            Utils.MyToast(Utils.KEYWORK_ERROR[0], R.drawable.warning_icon,
                    mContext, false);
        }
        isInitList = true;

        lvItem.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter1, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NewsItemView.class);
                if (!adapter.getItem(position).getLink().get(position)
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putSerializable(NewsItemView.ITEM_TEACHER,
                            adapter.getItemId(position));
                    bundle.putInt(NewsItemView.POSITION, position);
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    private void loadDataFromServer(String URL) {
        LoadData loadData = new LoadData() {
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ItemTeacher> result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                updateListView(result);
            }
        };
        loadData.execute(URL);

    }

    boolean isInitList = false;

    protected void updateListView(ArrayList<ItemTeacher> result) {
        if (!isInitList) {
            data.addAll(result);
        }
        isInitList = false;
        adapter.clear();
        adapter.addAll(result);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        AnimateFirstDisplayListener.displayedImages.clear();
    }

    class LoadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<ItemTeacher>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "", Utils.KEYWORK_ERROR[2]);
            data = new ArrayList<ItemTeacher>();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<ItemTeacher> doInBackground(String... params) {
            data = Utils.getInformationTeacher(params[0]);
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ItemTeacher> result) {
            if (result != null) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            } else if (result == null) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                Utils.MyToast(Utils.KEYWORK_ERROR[0], R.drawable.warning_icon,
                        mContext, false);
            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

    class InfoTeacher extends ArrayAdapter<ItemTeacher> {

        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        ImageLoadingListener animateFirstListener;
        List<ItemTeacher> item = new ArrayList<ItemTeacher>();

        public InfoTeacher(Context context, List<ItemTeacher> objects) {
            super(context, -1, objects);
            this.item = objects;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            animateFirstListener = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
            itemTeacher = getItem(position);
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.teacher_layout, arg2,
                        false);
                holder.Name = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_NameTeacher);
                holder.School = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_School);
                holder.ic_naviga = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.ivNaviga);
                holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.iv_IconTeacher);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            holder.Name.setText(itemTeacher.getName().get(position));
            holder.School.setText(itemTeacher.getSchool().get(position));
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return item.size();
        }

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView icon;
        TextView Name;
        TextView School;
        ImageView ic_naviga;
    }

    private static class AnimateFirstDisplayListener extends
            SimpleImageLoadingListener {

        static final List<String> displayedImages = Collections
                .synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view,
                Bitmap loadedImage) {
            if (loadedImage != null) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
                if (firstDisplay) {
                    FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                    displayedImages.add(imageUri);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void customLoadMoreDataFromApi(int page) {
        loadDataFromServer(URL + page);
    }

}
```

ItemTeacher

```
public class ItemTeacher {

    private ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> icon = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> link = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> school = new ArrayList<String>();


    public ItemTeacher(){

    }

    public ArrayList<String> getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getSchool() {
        return school;
    }

    public void setIcon(ArrayList<String> icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public void setLink(ArrayList<String> link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public void setName(ArrayList<String> name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setSchool(ArrayList<String> school) {
        this.school = school;
    }
}
```

And EndlessScrollListener

```
public abstract class EndlessScrollListener implements OnScrollListener {
    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    // The current offset index of data you have loaded
    private int currentPage = 0;
    // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
    private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
    // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
    private boolean loading = true;
    // Sets the starting page index
    private int startingPageIndex = 0;

    public EndlessScrollListener() {
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold, int startPage) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
        this.startingPageIndex = startPage;
        this.currentPage = startPage;
    }

    // This happens many times a second during a scroll, so be wary of the code
    // you place here.
    // We are given a few useful parameters to help us work out if we need to
    // load some more data,
    // but first we check if we are waiting for the previous load to finish.
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
        // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
        if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
            Log.i("abc", "ABC + totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount");
            this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
            this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            if (totalItemCount == 0) {
                this.loading = true;
            }
        }
        // If it’s still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
        // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the
        // current page
        // number and total item count.
        if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
            Log.i("abc", "ABC + totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount");
            loading = false;
            previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            currentPage++;
        }

        // If it isn’t currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
        // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
        // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to
        // fetch the data.
        if (!loading
                && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            Log.i("abc", "ABC + !loading");
            onLoadMore(currentPage + 1, totalItemCount);
            loading = true;
        }
    }

    // Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
    public abstract void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount);

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // Don't take any action on changed
    }
}
```

NullpointerException Error

```
01-03 08:53:44.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5051): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-03 08:53:44.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5051): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 30, size is 30
01-03 08:53:44.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
01-03 08:53:44.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
01-03 08:53:44.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at android.readnews.main.InfoTeacherFragment$InfoTeacher.getView(InfoTeacherFragment.java:215)
01-03 08:53:44.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2143)
01-03 08:53:44.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
01-03 08:53:44.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
01-03 08:53:44.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:638)
01-03 08:53:44.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4930)
01-03 08:53:44.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4087)
01-03 08:53:44.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
01-03 08:53:44.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
01-03 08:53:44.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:531)
01-03 08:53:44.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
01-03 08:53:44.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-03 08:53:44.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-03 08:53:44.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-03 08:53:44.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-03 08:53:44.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 08:53:44.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-03 08:53:44.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-03 08:53:44.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-03 08:53:44.379: E/AndroidRuntime(5051):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Update 1 :

Function get data from url

```
public static ArrayList<ItemTeacher> getInformationTeacher(String url) {
        // Vector<ArrayList<String>> data = new Vector<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> Name = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> School = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> Link = new ArrayList<String>();
        // ArrayList<String> Icon = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<ItemTeacher> itemTeachers = new ArrayList<ItemTeacher>();
        ItemTeacher itemTeacher = new ItemTeacher();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(10 * 300).get();
                Charset.forName("UTF-8");
                doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml);
                Elements eles = doc.select("div#Thu tbody a.linkheader");
                Elements elesIcon = doc.select("div#Thu img[src]");
                int i = 0;
                for (Element element : eles) {
                    i++;
                    String fillinfo = element.ownText();
                    String link = element.attr("href");
                    if (i % 2 == 0) {
                        School.add(fillinfo);
                        itemTeacher.setSchool(School);
                    } else {
                        Name.add(fillinfo);
                        itemTeacher.setName(Name);
                        Link.add(link);
                        itemTeacher.setLink(Link);
                        itemTeachers.add(itemTeacher);
                    }

                }

                for (Element icon : elesIcon) {
                    String hrefIcon = icon.attr("src");

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }

        }
        return itemTeachers;
    }
```

Comment: Please read [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

You're not understanding how ArrayAdapter should work. Each of your items should represent one row in your list. In your case, I think that's a single teacher. Thus, the first problem is that your InfoTeacher class should keep info for a single teacher, not the entire list.

```
public class ItemTeacher {

    private String name;
    private String icon;
    private String link;
    private String school;

    public ItemTeacher() {
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSchool() {
        return school;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setSchool(String school) {
        this.school = school;
    }
}
```

Now in your ArrayAdapter you don't need to store the list of items, because the adapter keeps the list of items. In getView, you use the position parameter to get a single ItemTeacher object, and then get that teacher's name, school, etc from the ItemTeacher object.

```
class InfoTeacher extends ArrayAdapter<ItemTeacher> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    ImageLoadingListener animateFirstListener;

    public InfoTeacher(Context context, List<ItemTeacher> objects) {
        super(context, -1, objects);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        animateFirstListener = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        ItemTeacher itemTeacher = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.teacher_layout, arg2, false);
            holder.Name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_NameTeacher);
            holder.School = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_School);
            holder.ic_naviga = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivNaviga);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_IconTeacher);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.Name.setText(itemTeacher.getName());
        holder.School.setText(itemTeacher.getSchool());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

It seems like there are still some problems, for example is "icon" really a String? It seems like it should be an integer resource ID, or a Drawable that you have loaded. But this should get you past your main ListView problems.

Comment: I use Arraylist because when i get data from website give me 30 items and when load more ( new page ) i want listview become 60 items and update.I update above

Comment: Yes, I understand you get more, but aren't you still showing a list of teachers, where each item in the list is a single teacher? If that's right, then your data object ItemTeacher needs to represent a single teacher who has one name and works at one school. It's fine to keep your "data" fields with the list of all teachers you've downloaded -- it can start with 30 and then go to 60.

Comment: Yes, Each item in list is a single teacher :). I will test it. Thanks for help :)